# PyCharm code completion red rectangle around certain elements?

Tags: python, django, code-completion, pycharm

When using autocomplete in pycharm I always get this weird looking red rectangle/square around the elements I'm writing and it messes up the whole flow. I have been looking into the PyCharm documentation but frankly I don't event know what I should be looking for and I haven't found anything with regard to *code completion*.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

http://i52.tinypic.com/2h5sm75.png

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image, warwaruk. I don't have the permissions yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your screenshot you've typed `<a` and PyCharm suggested you the completion options with the required attribute `href`, so just press Tab or Enter to get `<a href="|"` and continue typing the link.

If you don't like this behavior, it can be disabled in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac), `Editor` | `Smart Keys`, **XML/HTML** options group:

[image: XML/HTML completion]

Answer (score 0):

If you just dont like how it looks:

go to 'File -> settings' (alt+ctrl+s)

Then in 'IDE settings' +'editor' +'colors and fonts' in 'General' you will preview all IDE indications for your visual theme.

Here you can select another theme or change existing and save it as new.
Find indication that you dont like (in its optons box 'effects' is checked and in drop-down menu setted 'bordered' with red color)

Comment: Thanks for the help but CrazyCoder nailed it with his answer. :)